# How to use oAuth 2.0 in Google Apps Script to authorize Picasa Web Album

Tags: google-apps-script, picasa

I want to know how to use oAuth2.0 in Google Apps Script.

I want to use it in picasa.
This is my code for authorizing:

```
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Foauth2callback&response_type=code&client_id=" + My_Client_Id + "&approval_prompt=force&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Fdata%2F&access_type=offline&"
var option = {oAuthUseToken: "always", oAuthServiceName: "lh2"};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
```

However the authorizing is failed.

I know Google has written an example for linking picasa ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/picasa_google_apis ). However, it is for client login.
What I want to do is put some tags in some photos. Therefore the examples can not be used.

Comment: How about to use either the [Picasa Services](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/picasa-services) Library or the [OAuthApp](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/google-oauth) Library instead of writing own code?

Comment: Thanks for your replying, megabyte1024. 

I have already tried. However, I cannot find any function in it for tagging photo.

Comment: @megabyte1024: The Picasa Services Library it's not working, the OAuthApp Library link  returns Page not found error.

Answer (score 2):

from what I can see there you're urlFetchApp which current only supports OAuth1.0.  I would look at the steps outlined here for using OAuth 2.0 https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Auth.  I've not actually used Picasa authentication but I have set up OAuth 2.0 authentication for my site via Facebook so some of that may be useful - it's all on my blog here http://socialsamplr.blogspot.co.nz/.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Follow the instructions from https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

## Explanation

I tried to use the [Picasa Services Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/picasa-services) but the authentication process did not complete, so I took the library source code, adapted to use the OAuth file from https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2. I posted the result to https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/97cf176b8787d04e10929adf6aa7ae5f

### Steps followed

1. Got my own CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET from the Google Developers Console
2. Added SERVICE, SERVICE_URL, SCOPE as global variables to make it easy to use OAuth2 with other services later.

```
//Global variables to use Picasa Web Albums API
var SERVICE_ = 'lh2';
var SCOPE_ = 'http://picasaweb.google.com/data/';
var SERVICE_URL_ = 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default';

// Global variables for the project. Obtained from the Google Developers Console
var CLIENT_ID_ = '...';
var CLIENT_SECRET_ = '...';
```

Note: Steps 3 and 4 are optional. The alternative is to add them from the related library

3. Replaced OAuth2 script file by the file of the same name from https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/dist/OAuth2.gs.
4. Added the Underscore file from https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/dist/Underscore.gs.
5. Run the following code to get the redirect URI and register in the Google Developers Console

```
/**
 * Logs the redict URI to register in the Google Developers Console.
 */
function logRedirectUri() {
  var service = getService();
  Logger.log(service.getRedirectUri());
}
```

5. Get the CLIENT_I and CLIENT_SECRET from the Google Developer Console
6. Run the following code to authorize the script. Grab the URL shown and run it from a new tab.

```
/**
 * Authorizes and makes a request to the API.
 */
function run() {
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = SERVICE_URL;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      }
    });
    try {
      var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    } catch(e) {
      var result = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(),true);
      Logger.log(result.toXmlString());
    }
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
        authorizationUrl);
  }
}
```

4. Commented out original googleOAuth_()
5. Added the following code

   function googleOAuth_() {
   var service = getService();
   return {
     headers: {
       Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
     }
   }
   }